# ie7 evalJSON not working

Tags: javascript, json, wordpress, internet-explorer-7, prototypejs

I am trying to place a recent pages widget on wordpress. i created the js myself. on IE7 it always breaks. I have included `json2`,`json3`,`prototype.js`.

my code is below

```
var newRecentlyViewed = function(opts) {
    var that = {};
    var opts = opts || {};
    var cookieName = opts.cookieName || 'recently-viewed';
    var popupId = opts.popupId || 'recently-viewed-popup';
    var maxRecent = opts.maxRecent || 5;
    var cookieLifeHours = opts.cookieLifeHours || (24 * 0 * 0); /* 24 hours * 30 days * 24 months = 2 years */

    var futureDate = function(nHours) {
        var expire = null;
        if (nHours != null && nHours != 0) {
            var today = new Date();
            expire = new Date();
            expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * nHours);
        }
        return expire;
    };

    var setCookie = function(name, value, path, domain, secure, nHours) {
        var expires = futureDate(nHours);
        var curCookie = name + "=" + escape(value)
                + ((path) ? "; path=" + path : "")
                + ((domain) ? "; domain=" + domain : "")
                + ((expires) ? "; expires=" + expires : "")
                + ((secure) ? "; secure" : "");
        document.cookie = curCookie;
    };

    var getCookie = function(name) {
        var dc = document.cookie;
        var prefix = name + "=";
        var begin = dc.indexOf("; " + prefix);
        if (begin == -1) {
            begin = dc.indexOf(prefix);
            if (begin != 0)
                return null;
        } else {
            begin += 2;
        }
        var end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", begin);
        if (end == -1) {
            end = dc.length;
        }
        return unescape(dc.substring(begin + prefix.length, end));
    };

    var recent = function() {
        var cookie = getCookie(cookieName);
        var recentlyViewed = [];
        if (cookie != null) {
            recentlyViewed = cookie.evalJSON();
        }
        return recentlyViewed;
    };

    var remember = function(recentObj, uniqueKey) {
        var recently = recent();
        var now = new Date();
        now = now.getTime();
        var i;
        var dup_idx = -1;
        for (i = 0; i < recently.length; i += 1) {
            if (recently[i][uniqueKey] == recentObj[uniqueKey])
                dup_idx = i;
        }
        if (dup_idx > -1)
            recently.splice(dup_idx, 1);
        recently.push(recentObj);
        if (recently.length > maxRecent) {
            recently.splice(0, recently.length - maxRecent);
        }
        setCookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify(recently), "/", document.domain, false,
                cookieLifeHours);
    };

    /* Public functions are assigned to that */

    that.rememberPage = function(obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            obj = {
                url : '' + document.location,
                title : document.title
            };
        }
        remember(obj, 'url');
    };

    that.toggleDisplayPopup = function() {
        if ($(popupId).style.display != 'inline') {
            $(popupId).style.display = 'inline';
        } else {
            $(popupId).style.display = 'none';
        }
    };

    that.renderPopup = function() {
        var recentlyViewed = recent();
        var s, i;
        var url = top.location.href;
        if (url.search(/multi-client-data-library/i) < 1) {
            var recentlyViewedItemsContainer = $$("#" + popupId + " .recently-viewed-items")[0];
            if(jQuery(recentlyViewedItemsContainer).length){
                var recentlyViewedItems = recentlyViewedItemsContainer.select(".item");
                /* remove any existing div.item */
                for (i = 0; i < recentlyViewedItems.length; i++) {
                    recentlyViewedItems[i].remove();
                }
                for (i = 0; i < recentlyViewed.length; i++) {               
                    var recently = recentlyViewed[i];
                    var title = recently.title.substring(0, recently.title.length - 15);
                    if(title.length > 30) title = title.substring(0,27) + "... ";
                    s = "<div class=\"item\"><a href=\"" + recently.url + "\">"
                            + title + "</a></div>";
                    recentlyViewedItemsContainer.insert({
                        top : s
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    };

    that.clear = function() {
        setCookie(cookieName, JSON.stringify([]), "/", document.domain, false,
                cookieLifeHours);
        that.renderPopup();
    };

    that.onload = function() {
        that.rememberPage(); /* accessing a public function from a public function require that.*/
        that.renderPopup();
    };

    return that;
};
```

My [current](http://www.spectrumasa.com) site seems to work fine. if you browse to some of the pages with recent pages widgt on right hand side in IE7 you will see there are no errors. if you browse to [developing](https://gateway.spectrumasa.com:10443/investors/shareholder-information/trading) site it does not work.

[image: ie7 screenshot]

I have reverted back to `prototype.js` `v1.6.1`. JSON is not complaining anymore, however my code breaks which does not make sense as nothing has been changed from live version. also i get an error in `prototype.js`

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'getElementsByClassName'
```

Comment: And why do you still support IE7 ?

Comment: large part of users, still using ie7 to access site.

Comment: This is `$.evalJSON = function(src)
    {
        if (typeof(JSON) == 'object' && JSON.parse)
            return JSON.parse(src);
        return eval("(" + src + ")");
    };` - unless you can show some error I do not see what IE7 would not like there. Alternatively there is something else worng

Comment: i have put link up to page that is not working. could it be other scripts interferring or im loading extra scripts which i should not. like `json3`, `prototype`?

Comment: I do not have IE7 to test it with.

Comment: see screenshot from ie7

Comment: evalJSON is a prototype.js function. Is prototype.js loaded correctly?

Comment: i have placed prototype and json in header, without any conditional statements. still getting problem. you can view it in ie11 emulation mode.

Comment: Getting `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of undefined` in chrome for `var recentlyViewedItems = recentlyViewedItemsContainer
     .select(".item");` in recentpages.js

Comment: Please validate your page. I for example also get errors on `<!--<![endif]--><HTML` in IE 7 emulation

Comment: i have decided to remove prototype and json from ie7 completeley. thank you.

Comment: the code above was taken from curent site, in theory it should have worked but it did not.